# GKGameCenterViewController always shows Challenges instead of Leaderboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, game-center

I'm using [Apple's code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKit_Guide.pdf) to show a `GKGameCenterViewController`:

```
GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
if (gameCenterController != nil) {
    gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This is the text describing the code above:

> **Game Center UI is Displayed by Your View Controller (iOS)**
>
> The convention used by Game Kit is for one of your view controllers to present the Game Kit view controller. Your view controller acts as a delegate to the view controller it presents so that it can be informed when the player is finished looking at the presented screen. Listing 2-1 shows most common use of this pattern, which is to show the Game Center user interface. The Game Center view controller displays many different pieces of Game Center content, so most games should offer a button that brings the player to this screen, even if the game also shows Game Center content using a custom user interface.

When I use the recommended code I get to this screen (GameCenter Challenges), which is not what I want:

[image: GameCenter Challenges Screen]

I have also tried this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"gamecenter:"]];
```

By using that code, I get to the screen I expected to display:

[image]

Do I misunderstand something or am I doing something wrong? Shouldn't the first piece of code bring me to the main menu? Why won't it show the leaderboards?

**UPDATE**

I implemented `viewState` as suggested by [phix23](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15626483/814730):

```
GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
if (gameCenterController != nil) {
    gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
    gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
    [self presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But, it still displays the same Challenges screen, despite the fact that I want /try to display the Leaderboards screen.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? My `GKGameCenterViewController` seems to ignore the `viewState` value too; always opens to the same Game Center tab, regardless of what I set it to.

Comment: Any luck on this one. Mine always shows leader board where I am telling it to show me Achivements.

Answer (score 1):

The `GKGameCenterViewController` which is available since iOS 6 can show the leaderboards, achievements and challenges of your game center enabled application.

You can change the initial view by setting the `viewState` of the `GKGameCenterViewController`. If you don't set this property it will show the default view, which is the challenges view in your case. I guess you don't have setup any leaderboards or achievements so there is nothing to be shown.

Comment: try to use GKLeaderboardViewController instead

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
-(void)showGameCentersDefaultPage {
    GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
     if (gameCenterController != nil) {
           gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
           gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateDefault;
           [self presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
      }
}
```

If you want to begin with a specific type of GameCenter Leaderboard you can call the following method with your **leaderboardID**

```
- (void)showLeaderboard:(NSString*)leaderboardID {
    GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    if (gameCenterController != nil) {
        gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
        //The next three lines are the lines of interest...
        gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateDefault;
        gameCenterController.leaderboardTimeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeToday;
        gameCenterController.leaderboardCategory = leaderboardID;
        [self presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
     }  
}
```

Comment: Tried it all but still land at Challenge screen. I guess this is one were i have to accept i do not understand why as i do have code that works (old).

Answer (score 0):

Use `GKGameCenterViewController` and set the view state:

```
//Create a leaderboard view controller
GKGameCenterViewController *leaderboardViewController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
leaderboardViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;

//Set the time scope (ex. All Time, This Week, Today) and the leaderboard ID
leaderboardViewController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
leaderboardViewController.leaderboardCategory = leaderboardID;

//Set the delegate so we can handle various actions including dismissal
leaderboardViewController.leaderboardDelegate = self;

//Present the view controller
[self presentViewController:leaderboardViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This code will present a view controller that displays all of your games leaderboards (or the rankings if there is only one). You can also set properties such as which leaderboard to show, the time scope, delegate, etc. Also note that you can do a similar thing with achievements using the `GKAchievementViewController`.

The code that you provided in your question,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"gamecenter:"]];
```

Launches the GameCenter app. This means that iOS will **exit** your app and switch to GameCenter. This could be confusing to the user. You should also avoid making the user leave your app. Instead, use the `GKViewControllers` which are presented modally inside of your app.

Comment: `GKLeaderboardViewController` has been depreciated since iOS 7.0.

Comment: @Zorayr Is that why you downvoted? This is obviously an outdated answer, so that's not a valid downvote reason - at least give me a chance to edit it!

Comment: If it's outdated, delete the answer. People waste their time trying a depreciated method.

Comment: @Zorayr I will edit the question - it is a simple change which is documented in the Apple developer documents (a must read). This specific deprecated API is well documented and there are lots of StackOverflow questions on them; do your research! Please don't be negative. Additionally, the question is outdated (It's asking about iOS 6, not iOS 7) - so using your logic it should also be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 7.0, I use the following:

**Display Leaderboard:**

```
- (void)displayLeaderboard:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    if (gameCenterController != nil) {
        gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
        gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
        [viewController presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

**Display Achievements:**

```
- (void)displayAchievements:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    if (gameCenterController != nil) {
        gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
        gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateAchievements;
        [viewController presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Note that the view controller trying to use these functions will need to pass itself (i.e. *viewController* param must be set to some active view controller).

Hope this helps.